Could the "100 Prisoners Problem" strategy help find a private key from a public key in elliptic curve cryptography?
In elliptic curve cryptography (ECC), repeatedly adding the generator point G to itself essentially forms a long cycle, with the length of the cycle being equal to the order of the curve (the total number of distinct points on the curve).
Now, I was thinking about the 100 Prisoners Problem and its clever use of a deterministic strategy to follow loops or cycles, which dramatically increases the probability of success. This got me wondering if a similar strategy could be applied to break the cycle into shorter ones in ECC. Here's the idea:
Take the current point on the curve and use the x-coordinate of that point as a private key.
Then, calculate the corresponding public key by multiplying it with the generator point GG.
Afterward, add this newly calculated public key to the current point and repeat.

Could this process "break" the long cycle formed by repeatedly adding G, resulting in shorter cycles—similar to how the 100 Prisoners Problem follows deterministic loops? Is there any potential of exploiting such shorter cycles to find the private key, or is the mathematical structure of elliptic curves too secure for this analogy to work?
I'd love to hear some thoughts on this approach and whether it’s just theoretical or if there’s something deeper to explore here.

See the Pollard's Lamda...

TL/DR: No
You have not properly stated the 100 Prisoner's Problem in your question, see Wikipedia. More details about the problem are at the end of this answer.
In summary, the prisoners are numbered from 1 to 100 and they sample boxes where the numbers are stored, one in each box. Each prisoner can sample up to 50 boxes. The goal is to recover one's own number and thus survive, and the overall goal is for all prisoners to survive.
I don't think this approach applies to discrete log (EC based or otherwise). The goal there is to find one specific number (the discrete log) not one's own number. So the mechanism by which users join the cycle is missing.
More importantly, the definition of success in the prisoners game is too generous; if one was allowed to sample half the exponents (say $n/2$ where $n=2^t,$ for a $t-$bit discrete log problem) this would be a very inefficient attack and it would only be the work factor of a single prisoner, which is repeated over the game. The generic baby step giant step and Pollard rho attacks are much more efficient, with time complexity $O(\sqrt{n})$ (and in the case of baby step giant step similar memory is required but not for pollard rho). Pollard rho makes use of floyd's cycle finding algorithm so an ingredient for cycle finding is present.
100 Prisoners Problem: The prisoners are numbered from 1 to 100 and they sample boxes where the numbers are stored, one in each box. Each prisoner can sample up to 50 boxes. The goal is to recover one's own number and thus survive, and the overall goal is for all prisoners to survive which at first glance is $(50/100)^{100}=2^{-100}$ without a strategy.
The solution strategy depends on each prisoner using information on already opened boxes by others who came before them. So they open the box with their own number, and if that is not successful open the box with the number that they found in that box. This is repeated. Thus each prisoner opens up to 50 boxes, or quits with success.
This means each prisoner joins the same cycle and unless the cycle is longer than 50, which happens with relatively small probability, they all survive.

"This means each prisoner joins the same cycle" I couldn't understand this part. I think prisoners join random cycles and if all the cycles' length less than 51 then they win.
